Need an advise regarding connection to Mongo DB from my application
I am creating a learning application and need to connect to Atlas MongoDB. I am able to connect from Compass but not able to connect from the application. I am getting an error:

MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted.

I have checked the Network Access list and my IP is the only IP listed. It is correct, but is followed by /32 added automatically and there is no way to get rid of it. It can be edited (e.g. /24 or /16) but not deleted. Also I have tried to use

allow access from anywhere

but still get exactly the same error.
Here is connection string. The string was provided when creating the database, I have tried it as it shown below and also tried to use application name instead of the cluster name. But result was exactly the same as it mentioned above. Would be highly appreciate for the help. Codeium was not able to assist :)
mongodb+srv://myUserName:myUserPassword@traversyclaster.xxxxx.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=TraversyClaster

Does your computer has a fixed public IP? Not so common nowadays. What is your IP?

If you have a router between your computer and the Internet then the IP address that the database sees is the public address of the router, not the private address of the PC. Unfortunately, public addresses aren't always static. You may have to pay more for that.

And what wrong with "allow access from anywhere"? And why Compass is able to connect, but the application doesn't at the same time?

You have only provided part of the error message.  After the note about whitelisting, mongoose should provide the connection object that include the result of attempting to connect to each server.

@joe I have changed my code to the code provided by Atlas in Create connection modal but still have an error: MongoServerSelectionError: 64470000:error:0A000438:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert internal error:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\rec_layer_s3.c:1605:SSL alert number 80

Is tlsv1 enabled in those clusters?
